# PHP/MySQL - mapping table with 3 (not 2 as usually) columns to inherit permissions

Tags: mysql, inheritance, mapping

Making CMS to manage restaurants. Briefly, there are restaurants that have their own divisions. Also, there are meals that need to be assigned to a restaurant (so all its divisions can see those meals) or individual division(s) (so only selected division(s) can see meals).

So I created tables:

```
restaurant_id | restaurant_name
            1 | Restaurant 1
            2 | Restaurant 2


  division_id | restaurant_id    | division_name
          1   | 1                | 1-1
          2   | 1                | 1-2
          3   | 2                | 2-1
          4   | 2                | 2-2


      meal_id | meal_name
            1 | Steak
```

Also created mapping table `meals_to_restaurants_divisions` that contains 3 columns - `meal_id, restaurant_id, division_id`

So, if I want to assign meal to Restaurant 1 and ALL its divisions, I would create record:

```
meal_id | restaurant_id | division_id
      1 |             1 | null
```

If I want to assign meal only to division 2-2, I would create a record:

```
meal_id | restaurant_id | division_id
      1 |          null | 4
```

Could someone advise if such a scheme is correct? How could it be improved? I know someone will say I should only create mapping table with 2 records - `meal_id` and `division_id` and assign meal to all divisions instead of assigning to a restaurant, but here's the catch: if Restaurant 1 gets new division created in future, I want new division to inherit the same permissions (so if existing meal is assigned to a restaurant instead of division, all future divisions will inherit restaurant's permissions). Otherwise, I would need to manually edit every meal and assign a new division to it.

If someone is interested why I use `null` in `restaurant_id` in 2nd example, it's because if division's parent is changed later (division is assigned to another restaurant), I don't need to scan mapping table and change `restaurant_id` value there.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate if your model is *correct*, the most important aspect is that it fulfills all requirements. Since your description is not complete, we cannot verify that for you. You may e.g. check if devisions can belong to several restaurants at the same time. Or if you have other attributes for devisions (e.g. staff assigned to a devision, the order history, outstanding royalties or ratings on your website), that change or do not change when you move a devision to another restaurant. You could also think of that process as creating a new devision inside another restaurant and assigning all meals to the new devision (or maybe several devisions). It is more a conceptional question than a formal one, and if it is *correct* (and also if there is a better one) will depend on the requirements.

*Formally*, your model is correct, as long as you never set both `restaurant_id` and `division_id` in your "permission" table, because such an entry would not make any sense. (And as long as `restaurant_id` is not part of the key in your `devision` table, which is not the case according to your description).

Your table is basically a flattened 2-level-tree with some implicit conditions. A more general tree could look like

```
id | parent  
---+-------
1  | null           -- restaurant "1" (has no parent)
2  | 1              -- devision "1-1"
3  | 1              -- devision "1-2"
4  | null           -- restaurant "2"
5  | 4              -- devision "2-1"
6  | 4              -- devision "2-2"
```

In this tree, a restaurant would be treated like a normal devision (or a devision would be like a sub-restaurant), and you could assign meals to just that `id`. If you want to assign meal 1 to restaurant 1 and all its divisions, you would create the record `meal=1, id=1`. If you want to assign meal 1 only to division "2-2", you would create a record `meal=1, id=6`.

It implicitly prevents you from a situation where you would assign both `restaurant_id` and `division_id` to a meal (which is the mentioned condition in your model), as such a combination does not exist anymore. You "flattened" the tree by moving the parents into the `restaurant_id` and the (1st-level-)children to the `devision_id`-column of your `meals_to_restaurants_divisions`-table.

The tree will not enforce that a restaurant cannot belong to another restaurant or that you cannot have sub-sub-devisions. Basically, you treat restaurants explicitly NOT as a special kind of devision (or vice versa).

So both models, while formally correct, have a lot a implicit conditions that they automatically enforce (like the maximum depth in your model), that you would have to enforce manually (like not setting both columns in your model, or the maximum depth in the tree) or that are not supported (like subdivisions in your model). You will have to compare that to your requirements.

A site note: a tree is actually a bad model for hierarchical data in a database, as it gets complicated to (recursively) query several levels deep, and there are better models. I just used it for simplicity - and since you only have 1st-level-children, this restriction does not apply in your case.